# Connecting with a mysql

Tags: mysql

We are trying to interface between a MySQL database and Google API using ajax and php (on line 3 "phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php" dedfines the database info). We want to create a marker with the lat/long from Google API, but we get the fatal error on "add(Child)" 
Actual error message : "Call to a member function addChild() on a non-object"

How can we get the db to register and store the info?

```
<?php

require_once("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

$xml = ("mapPointInfo.xml") ;

$newLatLng = $_POST['latlng'];      //new markers LatLng
$newLatLng = substr($newLatLng, 1, -1);  //removes first and last characters of
newLatLng which are ( and )

list($newLat, $newLng) = explode(",", $newLatLng);


//$newLng = substr($newLng, 1, 0);

$locName = $_POST['geoNameMarker'];     //geocoded or simple incremented site name
$markerComment = $_POST['createMarker'];    //comment entered by user
$userName = $_POST['user'];         //acquire username from session
$voteValue = "likes";       //acquire vote value if any
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$timeStamp = date("m/d/Y G:i");         //get timestamp   
year:month:date:hour:minutes:seconds (example: 11:6:31:14:31:42)


if($markerComment == null || $markerComment == '' || $markerComment == ' '){
$markerComment = ' ';
}

$markerComment = htmlentities($markerComment, ENT_QUOTES);
$locName = htmlentities($locName, ENT_QUOTES);

$marker = $xml->addChild('marker');
$marker->addAttribute('lat', $newLat); 
$marker->addAttribute('lng', $newLng);
$marker->addAttribute('name', $locName); 
$marker->addAttribute('type', 'user-sug');


$comment = $marker->addChild('comment', $markerComment);   //add information to
latest/last marker
$comment->addAttribute('user', $userName); 
$comment->addAttribute('vote', 'likes');
$comment->addAttribute('time', $timeStamp); 


header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
header ('http://www.wmuhotspotmap.org/');
exit();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fatal error? You get **a** fatal error. What was it? I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that `$xml` is a string, but you're for some reason doing `$xml->addChild()` as if it were an object with functions.